# How to convert HEX chars to understand what attacker want to do

Tags: nginx, webserver

I am not able to convert it online to understand what he want to execute.

Please advise how to convert this characters.

```
198.46.148.155 - - [07/Jun/2021:22:39:41 +0300] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xF8\x01\x00\x00\xF4\x03\x03\xE7\x8B{\xE1\xBC\x89Zo\xCCy\x08~,V%\xBE\x
E79\x0B\x7F6\xF9\xD1\xC5\xD7\x15oWVV\x9Cr \xAFLGtoh\xC7W\x80\xDC4Sg\xC7\x16i\xFA\xDF\xCA\x11\xF1\xF9\xB3C\x09D<\xBC\x22!\xEF\xF6\x00&\x
C0/\xC00\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA8\xCC\xA9\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 166 "-" "-"
```

This is inbound to my webserver.

Thank you <3